# Initializing a static two dimensional map<int, int> in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stl, containers

I have two dimensional map

```
map <int, map<int, int>> _map;
```

The first type of initialization works well:

```
int i = 1,  j = 2,  k = 3;
map <int, map<int, int>> _map;
_map[i][j] = 100;
_map[i][k] = 200;
std::cout << _map[i][j] << ":" << _map[i][k] << std::endl;
```

Thus it prints:

```
100:200
```

However, the second initialization fails:

```
map <int, map<int, int>> _map = {
    {1, {{2, 100}}},
    {1, {{3, 200}}}
  };
  std::cout << _map[i][j] << ":" << _map[i][k] << std::endl;
```

The second prints:

```
100:0
```

I understand that map has "unique keys", on the other hand, we can init like "_map[i][j]".

Could you please explain me how **to initialize a static two dimensional map in a right way**?

Comment: Note that when you do `_map[i][k] = 200;` you don't initialize `_map[i]` because it was previously initialized when you did `_map[i][j] = 100;`, it simply accesses it. `operator[]` returns the element if it exists, otherwise adds it to the map and then returns it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it would be:

```
map<int, map<int, int>> _map = {
    {1, {{2, 100}, {3, 200}}}
  };
```

You could also have:

```
_map[1] = {{2, 100}, {3, 200}};
```

Your snippet

```
map <int, map<int, int>> _map = {
    {1, {{2, 100}}},
    {1, {{3, 200}}}
  };
```

would be "equivalent" (initialization versus insertion) to:

```
_map.insert({1, {{2, 100}}});
_map.insert({1, {{3, 200}}}); // Fails as key 1 already present.
```

Comment: This is correct, but could benefit from additional clarification on why the original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The two operations are not equivalent. This:

```
map <int, map<int, int>> _map;
_map[i][j] = 100;
_map[i][k] = 200;
```

First creates an entry in your map with key `i` and returns a reference to a value associated with your key - an `std::map<int, int>`, which then you apply `[j] = 100;` to. This means that `_map` has *one* element - a *key-value* pair of `{i, {j, 100}}`.

Then you apply `_map[i][k] = 200;`, which retrieves a value under `i` key (the very same `std::map<int, int>`) and puts a key-value pair of `{k, 200}` there. Your `_map` consists now of: `{i, {{j, 100}, {k, 200}}}`.

Now, why this doesnt work the same:

```
map <int, map<int, int>> _map = {
    {1, {{2, 100}}},
    {1, {{3, 200}}}
};
```

that's because here you introduce *two* key-value pairs. Twice with a key equal `1` with a value equal to separate maps. This is not equivalent. You would need to change your sytax to the following:

```
map<int, map<int, int>> _map = {
    {1, {{2, 100}, {3, 200}}}
};
```

This, like the first example, creates one entry (a key-value pair) to your map with a key `1` and a value `std::map<int, int>` consisting of two entries - `{2, 100}` and `{3, 200}`.